Azure chatbot integration with MS Teams gets hanged
I developed a chatbot using Azure language service with custom question answering. The bot is working fine in web chat, but when I added MS teams as a channel to the bot from the channels page of Azure bot service in portal and then when I click on the "Open in Teams", It tries to open the bot in Teams but gets hanged every time. Even other chats stop responding, so I had to kill the process.
What could be wrong with my configuration of the bot? Please note, I am doing this POC from a VS Enterprise subscription, while I have already integrated another chatbot (exactly same way) via my own "pay-as-you-go" subscription.
Is it that 2 chatbots cannot be integrated into a single Enterprise MS Teams? Or the issue is something else?
I tried everything I could think of (like stopping the web app service of the other bot, re-creating the new bot again from scratch with a new language service, changed the pricing tier of the service plan from free to basic), but no luck, any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if anyone needs more information to solve this.



You mention having two chatbots. Do they each have their own bot registrations in Azure? In the bot you are trying to run in Teams, are you using the ActivityHandler or the TeamsActivityHandler? You should be using the latter. Which BotFramework SDK are you using (C#, JS, or Python)? Are any errors listed in the Teams channel "Health Status" indicator (seen in the first image you posted)? If you haven't already, have you looked over and/or tried any of the Teams samples, located here?

@StevenKanberg - I haven't used any SDK for developing the bot. I used the GUI provided by Azure Language service studio --> Custom Question Answering.
Web App registrations is done one time when I created the web app for the first chatbot.
Anyways, the thing is, the issue got resolved without any changes to it. The next day the teams chat was working as expected. I am really not sure why it was stuck for the first day.

Sounds like it was a service disruption, most likely with Teams, that was mitigated by the time you returned the next day. Glad it's working now.
